# Div display with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-events

im starting to use Backbone.js and im trying to do somthing simple with javascript, which is show/hide divs. I get to show the div but i cannot hide it, i try many things, any idea? or could be it more sophisticated?

```
var Step1View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    events: {
        'click #more': 'more',
        'click #hide': 'hide',
    },

    initialize: function (){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'more', 'next', 'less');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function (){
        var self = this;
        $(this.el).append("<a id='more'>Show more</a>");
        $(this.el).append("<div id='show' style='display: none'>Div12</div>");
        return this;
    },

    more: function (){
        $('#more').text('Hide more');
        $('#more').attr('id', '#hide');
        $('#show').show();
    },

    less: function (){
        $('#hide').text('Show more');
        $('#show').hide();
    },

});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of problems here.

You're trying to bind an event to a non-existent `hide` method, your `events` should look like this:

```
events: {
    'click #more': 'more',
    'click #hide': 'less',
},
```

Your `initialize` method is trying to bind a method, `next`, which does not exist. Your `initialize` should look more like this:

```
initialize: function (){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'more', 'less');
    this.render();
},
```

Your `more` method is setting the `id` to `#hide` but it should be `hide`:

```
more: function (){
    $('#more').text('Hide more').attr('id', 'hide');
    $('#show').show();
},
```

Your `less` method doesn't switch the `id` back to `more`:

```
less: function (){
    $('#hide').text('Show more').attr('id', 'more');
    $('#show').hide();
}
```

And you have a stray comma after `less` which will make some browsers unhappy.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8HkdT/

Swapping the `id` attributes like that is a bit dodgy. You'd be better off with separate links that you show and hide along with the `<div>` or just a single *toggle* button that does both the showing and hiding.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone source code says:

```
// If `this.el` is a string, pass it through `$()`, take the first
// matching element, and re-assign it to `el`. Otherwise, create
// an element from the `id`, `className` and `tagName` properties.
```

Your code says: `el: $('body')`, but it's enough to say `el: 'body'`

And since Backbone 0.9, you can use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)`:

[http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-$el](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el)

And you probably wanted to write `'click #hide': 'less'` instead of `'click #hide': 'hide'`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, ill use the new notation, and u are right, better less than hide... :). Cheers.